Prevent soft hyphens in headings from appearing in the table of contents (TOC)
In LibreOffice Writer, soft hyphens that were manually inserted into long words that appear in headings are unconditionally displayed in the corresponding table of contents (TOC) entry.
Is there any way to prevent this from happening.
(Other than not using long words in the headings, but this is a technical document intended to be carried around in one's pocket.)
Page with heading:

TOC page with undesired hyphens:

Version: 24.2.6.2 (X86_64)
Build ID: 420(Build:2)
CPU threads: 22; OS: Linux 6.10; UI render: default; VCL: kf6 (cairo+wayland)
Locale: de-DE (en_US.UTF-8); UI: en-US
Calc: CL threaded


When inserting a manual hyphen, you must use Ctrl+Hyphen(-) to type it. You must not type the hyphen directly. If you do it directly, it will be shown on the table of contents. If you do it via Ctrl+Hyphen.
On the demo below, I first inserted the hyphen is inserted directly. Then, inserted it via Ctrl+Hyphen.


Thanks, I appreciate your answer. However, as the gray shading of the hyphens in the first screenshot reveals, these were indeed entered as CTRL+-. Also, in the TOC, the hyphens do not take up space, they just print over the other letters. Your recording is helpful in that I now know that it should work, there must be something specific about my document, I'll investigate.
